# Find the maximum sum of list values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need help trying to find the student who has the highest total scores.

```
s1= {'A': [100, 95, 100], 'B': [100, 100, 100], 'C': [95, 95, 80], 'D': [100, 100, 80]}
def wrtd2():
  for k, v in s1.iteritems():
     total = 0
     for i in v:
      total = total + i
     print total

wrtd2()
```

But it is printing the total for all students.

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Tip: Python has a `sum()` function that can be given a list

Comment: So just checking, that would be student B?

Comment: yes. this code is printing the total for all students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with a custom key function:

```
def wrtd2(s):
    return max(list(s.items()), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]))[0]

s1 = {'A': [100, 95, 100], 'B': [100, 100, 100], 'C': [95, 95, 80], 'D': [100, 100, 80]}
print(wrtd2(s1))
```

this will print

```
B
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a way to do it, using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
s1= {'A': [100, 95, 100], 'B': [100, 100, 100], 'C': [95, 95, 80], 'D': [100, 100, 80]}

print(max([(sum(score), student) for (student, score) in s1.items()])[1])
```

Output:

```
B
```

Comment: why the need to use sorted, then max the results?

Comment: Yeah just removed that, cheers @joelgoldstick :)

Comment: If you don't like using `lambda` @doer_123, then this is a good way.